# Apache 2.2 SSL Configuration..https responding as a blank home Page

Tags: apache, ssl, configuration

I am trying to implement SSL for one of our website. Website uses Apache 2.2 as web server and it then talks to Tomcat 7 over AJP protocol.

I have bought the certificate from Verisign. Also i was able to install the same on apache web server server..
To tell you about what configurations i have already done

httpd.conf

```
Listen 82
LoadModule ssl_module libexec/mod_ssl.so
Include etc/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

httpd-ssl.conf

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName test.domain.com:443
ServerAdmin root@test.domain.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /opt/csw/ssl/test.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/csw/ssl/test.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /opt/csw/ssl/test.crt
<Virtual Host>
```

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:82
NameVirtualHost *:443
Include etc/vhosts/test.conf
```

test.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:82 *:443>
    ServerName test.domain.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(test/registration.cfm) /test/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteRule ^/(index.cfm) / [P] 
    ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy balancer://testBal>
BalancerMember ajp://<tomcat_server>:8009/test
BalancerMember ajp://<tomcat_server2>:8009/test status=+h
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /test/admin/ !
    ProxyPass /test/ balancer://testBal/
    ProxyPass / balancer://testBal/
</VirtualHost>
```

Ok. Now the problem is whenever i am hitting the url https://test.domain.com I am getting blank page. However i see the site is being recognized as certified and i can also view the certificate.
What i see in apache access log - "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 209"
and in error log - "File does not exist: /opt/csw/apache2/share/htdocs/favicon.ico".
Tomcat server is running on 8080 port. I have been struggling for this issue for the last couple of days but to no avail. Appreciate your suggestion and help! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. So i think i have fixed this.below changes are made..

http-ssl.conf

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
#ServerName test.domain.com:443
ServerAdmin root@test.domain.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /opt/csw/ssl/test.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/csw/ssl/test.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /opt/csw/ssl/test.crt
<Virtual Host>
```

Somehow it came to me that server name is defined in test.conf so just commented here in http-ssl.conf and it worked like a charm. The website listens to http and https protocol as well..
To force to use https protocol..below changes can be made..i couldn't test this but i think it should work..if anyone has that requirement..for me it wasnt necessary..

test.conf

```
 <VirtualHost *:82 *:443>
 ServerName test.domain.com
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
 RewriteRule ^/(test/registration.cfm) /test/$1 [P,L]
 RewriteRule ^/(index.cfm) / [P] 
 ProxyRequests Off
 <Proxy balancer://testBal>
 BalancerMember ajp://<tomcat_server>:8009/test
 BalancerMember ajp://<tomcat_server2>:8009/test status=+h
 </Proxy>
 ProxyPass /test/admin/ !
 ProxyPass /test/ balancer://testBal/
 ProxyPass / balancer://testBal/
 </VirtualHost>
```

Thank you!

Comment: thanks, commenting the `Servername` directive from the `httpd-ssl.conf` in the `<Virtualhost _default_:443>` block did the trick for me. Though I don't understand why this Apache/vhost/ssl question is off topic and the other ones are not...